# How to check if a certain df['column'] contains a word from a list Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, loops

Any tips on how to see if a certain word is inside pandas column?

```
# initialise data of lists.
data = {'Colour':['Blue andtext', 'Greys', 'Potato', 'Yellow','Tree'],
        'Values':[20, 21, 19, 18,44]}
 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Let's say:

```
colours = ['Blue','Grey','Yellow']
```

How do I check if df2['Colour'] is actually a colour and represent it in a new column?

Output should be

```
Colour           Value   Actualcolour
Blue andtext     20      Blue
Greys            21      Grey
Potato           19      NaN
Yellow           18      Yellow
Tree             44      Nan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.Series.where` and `isin`:

```
df2["Actualcolour"] = df2["Colour"].where(df2["Colour"].isin(colours))

print (df2)

   Colour  Values Actualcolour
0    Blue      20         Blue
1    Grey      21         Grey
2  Potato      19          NaN
3  Yellow      18       Yellow
4    Tree      44          NaN
```

Or use `pd.Series.extract` and add word boundary or ignore case if required:

```
df2["ActualColor"] = df2["Colour"].str.extract(f"({'|'.join(colours)})")

print (df2)

         Colour  Values ActualColor
0  Blue andtext      20        Blue
1         Greys      21        Grey
2        Potato      19         NaN
3        Yellow      18      Yellow
4          Tree      44         NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately i stated my wrong the first time, could you look at it again?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
df2['ActualColour'] = [x if x in colours else np.NaN for x in df2.Colour]
```

You could also convert `colours` into a df and left join them

Comment: Thanks for the answer! By accident i stated my question wrong the first time, if you have time could you take a second look?

Answer (score 0):

Another possible answer is to apply a function to the column in question using `.apply`:

```
df2["ActualColour"] = df2["Colour"].apply(lambda x: x if x in colours else np.nan)
```